# Repeat block of text for each DIV instance

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get text to showup after each post in my Tumblr theme, and the javascript works in the jsfiddle, but not when I include it into the theme. Am I missing something?

http://jsfiddle.net/KP3uw/70/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="stat-wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="stat-wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="stat-wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="stat-wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="stat-wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="counter"></div>
</div>
```

**JAVSCRIPT**

```
  /*global */

  function statwrap() {
      var count;
      var counter;
      var bob;
      count = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
      counter = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
      bob = document.getElementsByClassName('stat-wrap');
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
          bob[i].innerHTML = "jkfdgdff14";
      }
  }
  window.onload = statwrap();
```

Here's my tumblr theme I have pasted the javascript into btw. (http://lgbtvee.tumblr.com/) I've tried both just above `</head>` and `</body>` ending tags but it didn't work either place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have made this wayy to complicated.

Try using jQuery and using the append() function:

```
$( ".stat-wrap" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KP3uw/74/

Comment: Annnnnnd you are officially my hero! I know nothing about jQuery so that's why I was just going with my limited knowledge of javascript hoping I got somewhere with it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's not exactly answer to your question but you can add some content to all elements with css `:after`.

```css
.stat-wrap:after {
    content: "jkfdgdff14";
    display: block;
}
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/t0ro94dz/

Answer (score 0):

I would have made this a comment, but don't have enough reputation to do it yet.

Your loop's condition `i < counter` is off, I think.  The variable `counter` is tied to `innerHTML`, which I believe is a string (not a number).  Try changing it to `i < count`.

--edit--

I also noticed that your theme is throwing 2 of the same errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

since you don't actually have any elements with the ID of `counter` on the page.  Also, in the page source, your script is repeated twice.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is not working but there are so many divs. Maybe you want limit and say

```
count = document.getElementsByClassName('post').length;
```

Also can you check if you need to parse innerHTML into int using parseInt, some JS compilers can scream

```
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
count = parseInt(document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML);

       OR simply 

document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML =  count
counter = count
```